# OpenCV Build - No CMAKE_Swift_COMPILER could be found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, opencv

I'm trying to build an opencv.framework for iOS. But I'm getting this error.

XCode 13.4.1

Swift 5.6.1

CMake 3.23.2

Device Macbook Air M1

```
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode-13.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- The Swift compiler identification is Apple
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (enable_language):
  No CMAKE_Swift_COMPILER could be found.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/egehan/Desktop/opcv/ios/build/build-armv7-iphoneos/modules/objc/framework_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
============================================================
ERROR: Command '[u'cmake', u'-GXcode', u'-DAPPLE_FRAMEWORK=ON', u'-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install', u'-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', u'-DOPENCV_INCLUDE_INSTALL_PATH=include', u'-DOPENCV_3P_LIB_INSTALL_PATH=lib/3rdparty', u'-DFRAMEWORK_NAME=opencv2', u'-DIOS_ARCH=armv7', u'-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/egehan/Desktop/opcv/opencv/platforms/ios/cmake/Toolchains/Toolchain-iPhoneOS_Xcode.cmake', u'-DCPU_BASELINE=DETECT', u'/Users/egehan/Desktop/opcv/ios/build/build-armv7-iphoneos/modules/objc_bindings_generator/ios/gen', u'-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fembed-bitcode', u'-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fembed-bitcode', u'-DBUILD_ROOT=/Users/egehan/Desktop/opcv/ios/build/build-armv7-iphoneos', u'-DCMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL=install_name_tool', u'--no-warn-unused-cli']' returned non-zero exit status 1
============================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 181, in build
    self._build(outdir)
  File "opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 139, in _build
    self.buildOne(target[0], target[1], main_build_dir, cmake_flags)
  File "opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 327, in buildOne
    execute(cmakecmd, cwd = builddir + "/modules/objc/framework_build")
  File "/Users/egehan/Desktop/opcv/opencv/platforms/apple/cv_build_utils.py", line 13, in execute
    retcode = check_call(cmd, cwd = cwd)
  File "/Users/egehan/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '[u'cmake', u'-GXcode', u'-DAPPLE_FRAMEWORK=ON', u'-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install', u'-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', u'-DOPENCV_INCLUDE_INSTALL_PATH=include', u'-DOPENCV_3P_LIB_INSTALL_PATH=lib/3rdparty', u'-DFRAMEWORK_NAME=opencv2', u'-DIOS_ARCH=armv7', u'-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/egehan/Desktop/opcv/opencv/platforms/ios/cmake/Toolchains/Toolchain-iPhoneOS_Xcode.cmake', u'-DCPU_BASELINE=DETECT', u'/Users/egehan/Desktop/opcv/ios/build/build-armv7-iphoneos/modules/objc_bindings_generator/ios/gen', u'-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fembed-bitcode', u'-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fembed-bitcode', u'-DBUILD_ROOT=/Users/egehan/Desktop/opcv/ios/build/build-armv7-iphoneos', u'-DCMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL=install_name_tool', u'--no-warn-unused-cli']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Edit: I tried it with an intel macbook and was able to compile without any problems.

Comment: Install latest version of CMAKE.

Comment: @toyotaSupra It's already latest.

Comment: Updating CMake did indeed fix this issue for myself, for a non OpenCV project.

Comment: @Cameron I tried with intel macbook, it solved my problem.